# How to check if an array is in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I'd want to check, using a filtering query, if an array is equal to an element of another multidimensional array which can be considered as an array of arrays.

For example:

Given the multidimensional array `{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}` I want to check if a one dimension array of one of the array elements.

Expected results:

- Input: `{1,2}` or `{3,4}` -> Output: `TRUE`
- Input: `{2,3}` or `{1,5}` -> Output: `FALSE`

I've already tried `<@`, but it returns `TRUE` for all the examples cases and I can't use `ANY` without slicing the multidimensional array.

Does anyone have a solution without using `pgplsql`?

Comment: Can ypu what hou have tried?

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a difficult problem to solve without any pgpsql. However, if this function is utilized, it is much simpler:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reduce_dim(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$function$
DECLARE
    s $1%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOREACH s SLICE 1  IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
        RETURN NEXT s;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

To use:

```
 create table array_test (arr integer[][]);
 insert into array_test (select '{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}');

 select (case when '{1,2}' in (select reduce_dim(arr) from array_test) then true 
         else false end);
 case
 ------
 t
(1 row)

select (case when '{1,4}' in (select reduce_dim(arr) from array_test) then true 
         else false end);
 case
------
 f
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: search in array like in string:

```
select '{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}'::int[][]::text like '%{1,2}%';
```

Complex way: decompose array to slices (without `plpgsql`):

```
with t(x) as (values('{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}'::int[][]))
select *
from t
where (
  select bool_or(x[s:s] = '{{1,3}}') from generate_subscripts(x,1) as s);
```